# Python Streamlit Cached Data

Tags: python, multithreading, streamlit

I have developed a user-interactive dashboard in Python using Streamlit. However, I am uncertain about some aspects of my code. Essentially, this dashboard provides predictions for revenue and the number of transactions for the next five months for the pay and ship product. To accomplish this, it relies on a ML model that is trained and updated every month. To ensure the dashboard is regularly updated, I have to clear the cached data from the previous month. While I have a solution in place with threads (check the piece of code below), I'm not confident it's the most performance-efficient one. The idea is to have a process running in background.. I've also considered using asyncio, although I lack experience with it. Could you please provide tips or ideas to enhance my code? I also sense that it may not be the most professional approach, i.e, missing some OOP programming...

Thank you

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
 
 @st.cache_data()
 def load_model():
     mlflow_client = mlflow_manager.MLFlowManager(experiment_id, bucket_name, mlflow_url)
     mlflow_client.download_artifacts(sub_experiment="atv", destination_folder="data")
     model_tx = mlflow_client.get_model("ps_monthly_forecast_num_txs")
     model_atv = mlflow_client.get_model("ps_monthly_forecast_atv")
     return model_atv, model_tx
 
 
 def refresh_cache():
     while True:
         current_date = datetime.now()
         target_date = (current_date.replace(day=1) + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(
             day=10, hour=7, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0
         )
         time_difference = target_date - current_date
         seconds_until_target = time_difference.total_seconds()
         time.sleep(seconds_until_target)
         st.cache_data.clear()
 
 
 def main():
     if "is_running" not in st.session_state:
         st.session_state.is_running = True
         thread = threading.Thread(target=refresh_cache)
         thread.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this is a bit to broad to elicit high-quality, specific feedback. I recommend trying to narrow it down. For example, is it necessary that mlflow be part of this? Could that be swapped with just reading a model from a local file? This would also benefit from being more specific than "enhance my code"... e.g. are you looking for help making it faster? more portable? easier to test? easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit lets you handle this natively in st.cache_data.  There is a ttl parameter you can add to the call.

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_data